# Cosa significa "prendeva il filo e faceva le parti" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel racconto *Casa d'altri* di Silvio D'Arzo ho letto:

> Era buio e già c’era la luna: i monti e le siepi e le strade e le lapidi del cimitero (fatta eccezione dei boschi che non eran nient’altro che macchie) apparivano piú chiari che al sole. Non erano ancora le sette, e in ogni casa la vecchia **prendeva il filo e faceva le parti**.

Non capisco cosa vuol dire "prendeva il filo e faceva le parti" in questo brano. La frase potrebbe far riferimento (non ne sono sicura) a una vecchia lavandaia, che è uno dei personaggi del racconto. Ho cercato alla voce "filo" in parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato niente al riguardo. Potreste spiegarmi il significato di questa frase nel passaggio sopra citato?

**Aggiornamento:** Un'altra frase tratta dal libro che forse può aiutare a capire il contesto:

> Alle sei scendevate in strada e non sentivate altro che odor di polenta e castagne bollite nell’acqua.

Comment: Potrebbe trattarsi dell'usanza di tagliare la polenta a fette con un filo di cotone, il fatto che questa operazione sia fatta dalla vecchia fa pensare a una società contadina matriarcale. Non so però se questo sia il contesto del racconto.

Comment: @CasaMich È quello che pensavo anch'io ([link](https://i.pinimg.com/236x/a7/5c/45/a75c4565eefcc55ee99073d26f90adec--copper-polenta.jpg)). Il contesto è poco, ma è la prima spiegazione che mi viene in mente. Hai voglia di formularlo in una risposta?

Comment: @CasaMich: Anche a me sembra plausibile tenendo conto della frase che ho aggiunto. Ti andrebbe di scrivere la risposta?

Comment: Ero nel dubbio, dato che l'usanza mi sembrava più comune in Lombardia e Veneto piuttosto che in Emilia dove era disponibile anche il grano tenero oltre al mais. Ma la frase aggiunta, che parla di polenta, mi ha reso più sicuro.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La scena descrive l'ora di cena nelle case contadine dell'Italia settentrionale dove il cibo più comune, all'inizio del secolo scorso, era la polenta, che veniva tagliata a fette con un filo di cotone, per non sprecarne nemmeno quella piccola quantità che poteva rimanere attaccata alla lama.
Il compito di fare le parti era affidato alla donna più anziana, che aveva il potere di assegnare la giusta razione a ciascuno dei commensali.